# Add a count to a row relative to the number of similar rows in a table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table of orders for a product and I need to figure out for each order which number of orders that is for the particular customer.  So let's say John Smith has ordered 4 times with the email john@smith.com I need to add a number to each order in the table to represent the number of orders that order is for that customer.  Thus, the 3rd order in the list with email john@smith.com would have a column that said 3.

I've tried to use a subquery which counts the number of orders for each customer, but that will show the same count of orders for each customer instead of whether or not that order is the first, second, third, etc order for that particular customer.  Database I am running is Postgres.

```
SELECT
    order_date,
    email,
    count as order_count
FROM (
    SELECT
        CAST(date_trunc('day', (order_order.created at time zone 'pst')) AS DATE) AS order_date,
        order_order.email,
        order_order.subscription_id,
        count_orders.count
    FROM
        order_order
        JOIN (
            SELECT
                order_order.email AS customer_email,
                COUNT(*)
            FROM
                order_order
            GROUP BY
                order_order.email) AS count_orders ON order_order.email = count_orders.customer_email
        ORDER BY
            order_order.created DESC) b
ORDER BY
    order_date DESC;
```

This is what I would like to return:

```
order_id   email            number_per_customer
========  =======          ==================
40        john@smith.com    4
30        john@smith.com    3
20        john@smith.com    2
10        john@smith.com    1
```

What I am currently getting is this:

```
order_id   email            number_per_customer
========  =======          ==================
40        john@smith.com    4
30        john@smith.com    4
20        john@smith.com    4
10        john@smith.com    4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no idea what your query has to do with your question.  It references a bunch of tables and conditions not mentioned in the question.

But you seem to want a window function.  *Based on the text* this slooks like:

```
select o.*, row_number() over (partition by email order by order_id asc) as order_cnt
from orders o;
```

Comment: Don't you want to number by ascending id?

Comment: @shawnt00 . . . Yes.  Thank you.

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff.  You are right about my above query. I simplified it to make it more applicable to the question.